# What SQL query to update rows in one table that are between values of a row in another table?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have the following scenario in my SQL Server, the exact naming or contents does not matter its more about the operation I need to do.

#### Table [Items]

There could be multiple rows per id

| id | timestamp | data_value | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 08:00:00 | 10.5 |  |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 08:30:00 | 11.2 |  |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 09:00:00 | 9.8 |  |
| 2 | 2023-09-01 08:15:00 | 7.3 |  |
| 2 | 2023-09-01 08:45:00 | 8.0 |  |

#### Table [ItemsMaintenance]

There could be multiple rows per id, periods do not overlap.

| id | start_timestamp | stop_timestamp | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 08:00:00 | 2023-09-01 08:45:00 | done |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 08:45:00 | 2023-09-01 09:00:00 | not_done |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 09:00:00 | 2023-09-01 09:15:00 | done |
| 2 | 2023-09-01 09:15:00 | 2023-09-01 09:45:00 | done |
| 2 | 2023-09-01 09:45:00 | 2023-09-01 10:30:00 | not_done |

### Problem to solve

Both tables grow in size on daily basis.
What I want to achieve is to update status column in **[Items]** table with the value from status from **[ItemsMaintenance]** if the **[Items].timestamp** fits between respective **[ItemsMaintenance].start_timestamp** and **[ItemsMaintenance].stop_timestamp**.

So in this case first row of **[Items]** should be updated with ***done*** since it is between the values of first row in **[ItemsMaintenance]**.

Comment: What is the rule for updating the `'2023-09-01 08:30:00'` row in `items`, when there are two conflicting matching rows in `ItemsMaintenance` - `08:00:00` to `08:45:00` and `08:15:00` to `09:00:00`?

Comment: i'd say row 2 and 3 overlap each other

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion I introduced, this is how the table can look like, now with the correct periods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the the conflicting overlapping `ItemsMaintenance` rows was an error in the sample data, you can just join the tables and update the item status. The following also assumes that stop_timestamp is *exclusive*.

```
UPDATE I
SET status = IM.status
FROM Items I
JOIN ItemsMaintenance IM
    ON IM.id = I.id
    AND IM.start_timestamp <= I.timestamp
    AND I.timestamp < IM.stop_timestamp 
WHERE I.status IS DISTINCT FROM IM.status -- Don't update values already set
```

If your data may actually contain overlapping conflicting `ItemsMaintenance` rows, you will need to define a rule for which one applied and use `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...)` to select the one that should be applied. The following will prefer the `ItemsMaintenance` row with the latest `start_timestamp`.

```
UPDATE I
SET status = IM.status
FROM Items I
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM ItemsMaintenance IM
    WHERE IM.id = I.id
    AND IM.start_timestamp <= I.timestamp
    AND I.timestamp < IM.stop_timestamp 
    ORDER BY IM.start_timestamp DESC
) IM
WHERE I.status IS DISTINCT FROM IM.status -- Don't update values already set
```

A `CROSS APPLY` is like a join to a subquery. The `IS DISTINCT FROM` comparison is similar to `<>` (not equal) but also safely handles `NULL` values.

If your data is expected to grow considerably, I would advise adding logic to avoid scanning all data for changes every time the update statement is run. Perhaps you can limit the `timestamp` to just those since N days ago. Another approach would be to define triggers on the Items and ItemsMaintenance tables and only update rows with matching `id` values when data for that `id` value changes.

If there is ever a case where `ItemsMaintenance` rows might be deleted, you may need to change the `JOIN` or `CROSS APPLY` to a `LEFT JOIN` or `OUTER APPLY`, so that the associated `Item.status` value might be reset to null or blank. The `SET` clause could be rewritten as `SET status = ISNULL(IM.status, '')` to map a no-match to a blank status.

And be sure to add appropriate indexes for efficiency.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WIK-sqxv) for a working demo.

Comment: Data is definitely expected to grow considerably, what would be better solution, to limit the timestamp or to define the triggers, how would you define such a trigger? Thanks a lot for your detailed answer from above! I actually made a mistake in the ItemsMaintenance table, the periods only overlap such that stop_timestamp of 1st row will be the same as start_timestamp of the next one, order chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE 
     Items
SET 
     Items.status  = 'done'
FROM 
     Items t1 
     INNER JOIN ItemsMaintenance t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id;
 WHERE
     t1.timestamp >= t2.start_timestamp AND   t1.timestamp < t2.stop_timestamp
```